# Creating synthetic user data in R; issues with generating user identifier variable

Tags: r, string, dataframe, events, random

I am trying to generate synthetic user event log data for demonstration purposes. It's going to be very basic feature-wise (about 4 variables altogether). Here is what I have so far:-

```
require(wakefield)#for generating the Status variable
require(dplyr)
require(stringi)


set.seed(1)
#data<-data.frame()
eventDate<-seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2015-12-31"), by = "1 day")
eventDate<-sample(rep(eventDate,each=1000),replace = T)

u <- runif(length(eventDate), 0, 60*60*12) # "noise" to add or subtract from some timepoint
eventDateTime<-as.POSIXlt(u, origin = paste0(eventDate,"00:00:00"))
eventDateTime

eventOutcome<-r_sample_factor(x = c("Passed", "Failed", "Ongoing","Unknown"), n=length(eventDate))
eventOutcome

data<-data.frame(eventDate,eventDateTime,eventOutcome)
head(data)

# eventDate       eventDateTime eventOutcome
#1 2015-01-25 2015-01-25 04:48:47      Unknown
#2 2015-05-05 2015-05-05 09:35:22      Unknown
#3 2015-11-28 2015-11-28 08:56:16       Failed
#4 2015-05-23 2015-05-23 02:24:52      Ongoing
#5 2015-01-26 2015-01-26 07:43:52       Failed
#6 2015-10-22 2015-10-22 03:07:14       Passed
```

There is about 365000 rows of data here. All that is left to do is add a user identifier variable. I would like it if some users will maybe have a handful of interactions recorded in the  data set, whereas some users may have dozens/hundreds/thousands of interactions (I would like this dataset to have that kind of variability).

I can create a user identifier variable no problem:-

```
UserId<-stri_rand_strings(1300,6)
```

But if I add this to the data, it doesn't work:-

```
data$UserId<-stri_rand_strings(1300,6)

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, UserId, value = c("k3QlXs", "gK3eBa",  : 
  replacement has 1300 rows, data has 365000
```

So my request two-fold: How can I assign a User identifier variable to this kind of data; how can I make it variable, where some users have a 1 or a few interactions whilst others will appear frequently (i.e. dozens, hundreds, thousands of times)?

Thank you in advance for any help, always appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the distribution of user IDs you are looking for is something akin to a power law or [Pareto distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution). This is a way to generate a vector of relative probabilities of sampling each user ID that follows a power law, then sample the user IDs following those relative probabilities.

Here I've used the function `Pareto::rPareto` to generate the relative probabilities. You can vary the parameters, especially `alpha`, to get different distributions. As `alpha` increases the distribution will become more even. I also supplied a `truncation` parameter so that you will not get too many users with unrealistically high numbers of purchases (In this example the most frequent ID has ~3700 cases).

Note you are not guaranteed to sample each of the 1300 user IDs at least once with this particular way of doing it.

Next I use the function `uuid::UUIDgenerate` to generate 1300 unique strings. Finally I use `sample` to sample the unique IDs with replacement as many times as you have rows in your data frame. I plot the frequencies of the different IDs in the sample. Again, modify the parameters if this distribution is not what you are looking for.

```
library(Pareto)
library(uuid)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)

n_users <- 1300
n_rows <- 365000

relative_probs <- rPareto(n = n_users, t = 1, alpha = 0.3, truncation = 500) 
unique_ids <- UUIDgenerate(n = n_users)

id_sample <- sample(unique_ids, size = n_rows, prob = relative_probs, replace = TRUE)

# Check the distribution of IDs
ggplot(as.data.frame(table(id_sample)), aes(x = Freq)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  scale_x_log10()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @qdread, this looks really good and I like that you can play about with this i.e. toggle the distributions. I'll keep working with this to find the kind of distribution that I am after. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

One option might be to generate a UUID for each user.  A UUID looks like this:

```
c7f2dde5-dfeb-45cb-9720-87b23effd45d
```

If you use a good UUID generator, then it is almost impossible to generate the same UUID more than once.  R has a `uuid` package which can be used:

```r
library(uuid)

user_uuid <- UUIDgenerate()
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for your answer. It works in creating a user identifier variable. I was wondering if there was a way to make it more variable in relation to how the rows are distributed among each user id? For instance, a cohort of users having only a few interactions and others having way more i.e. dozens/hundreds?

Comment: @Robin But that almost sounds like the identifier wouldn't be truly random.

Comment: Yeah I see your point. The way I would like this to be is something similar to a purchase event log on a retail website, where a cohort of users make a single one-off purchase and another cohort would make repeat purchases over time; I'd like the rows to be distributed across the user identifiers in a similar fashion

Answer (score 1):

You are generating 1300 strings but number of rows in your `data` is 365000. So you can use `sample` to repeat those 1300 string randomly.

```
library(stringi)
data$UserId <- sample(stri_rand_strings(1300,6), nrow(data), replace = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, thank you for your quick response. This works in generating an ID variable well. I was wondering if there was a way to make it more variable in number of rows distributed across each ID. For instance, a cohort of users only having a few rows attributed to them and a cohort having way more than a few rows? I hope this makes sense

Comment: `sample` has `prob` argument where you can define the probability of each value occurring. Although defining probability for 1300 values will not be simple. Other than that  there is no easy way in which you can control the randomness for each ID. You need to come up with rules that you want to check for and discard the values which do not fit those criteria and generate ID's for them again.